# How to wait the p2 profile gets completed

Tags: eclipse, p2

We are using p2 to update our RCP application, and this worked so far quite well until today I realized in some case the P2 IProfile was emty (not null but empty) and always of course return emty result queries.

This happend when launching the application only, meaning that if I request the same profile later in time, I get a complete profile.

The Javadoc of IProfile mention the fact that profile is a snapshot of a particular state.
So it seems I am querying the ProfileRegistry to early and the profile is not yet complete.
I could not find any way on the javadoc to wait for a profile to be filled properly.

I would be grateful to anyone that would help me solve this problem nicely, because using a sleep (which works) is not an acceptable solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to P2 hell. Can you show your code? When do you query the profile registry? Which profile do you load? Etc.

Comment: see my answer post, I hate that kind of code and if you have a better solution, I'd be glad.

Answer (score 0):

here is the ugly solution I am implemented, basically testing the time stam to be sure the profile has been loaded

```
// there seems to be a bug because if the agent is created too quickly then the profile is empty.
// so we loop until we get a proper profile
do {
    try {
       Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       interrupted = true;
    }
    if (agent != null) {
       agent.stop();
    }
    agent = agentProvider.createAgent(getP2AgentUri());
    IProfileRegistry profRegistry = (IProfileRegistry) agent.getService(IProfileRegistry.SERVICE_NAME);
    profile = profRegistry.getProfile(getP2ProfileId());
} while (profile != null && profile.getTimestamp() == 0 && !interrupted && !progress.isCanceled());
```

The profile I use is *SELF* but I use a method to get the ProfileId because I have JUnit tests that are base on another external p2 profile.

Comment: When do you start the execution of this loop? A naive guess is that the P2 machinery is just "not there" to this point and the profile you get is NULL. Then it may have to do with bundle start levels in your Equinox container.

Comment: If you look at what I wrote I never said the profile is Null, that the point, the profile is not null, like it was found by p2 but not yet fully red. This loop is started right after the eclipse workbench is created, in a **org.eclipse.ui.startup** extension point.

Comment: Ok, I see "not null but empty". Was just confused by "profile != null" check in your "while" statement.
However, I can't reproduce this misbehavior. Have you checked how many times you need to re-query P2? You can also turn on some P2 tracing on to see more what's happening: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/TracingOptions Or debug into the code...